# Delete two lines with sed if no text between them

Tags: awk, sed

i have a file that contain the following text:

```
[Data]

hi

[Data]

one two three

[Data]

[Data]

right left

[Data]

[Data]
```

I am looking how to get this output from sed, awk or something:

```
[Data]

hi

[Data]

one two three

[Data]

right left
```

Explanation: i need to look if between [Data] and [Data] have no text, if not contain text i need to delete the [Data] line and the next empty line.

Can you help me? many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n/&/3;Ta};/^\[Data\][^\n]*\n\n[^[][^\n]*\n$/b;s/\n//;D' file
```

This keeps a rolling window of 4 lines in the pattern space and if the expected pattern is not found, deletes the first two lines then regenerates the pattern space back up to 4 lines and repeats.

Comment: Hi potong, this work as desired. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The title says `sed` but it is also tagged `awk`, so try:

```
awk '$0==s && p==$0{next} {p=$0}1' s="[Data]" file
```

This is presuming there are no empty lines every other line in the real data sample.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/###/g' file | sed 's/######\[Data\]######\[Data\]/######\[Data\]/g' | sed 's/###/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful.

```
sed ':a;/$/{N;s/\n/#/;ba}' inputFile.txt|sed 's/\]#*\[Data\]/\]/g'|sed 's/#/\n/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you SAY you want to do using GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\[Data\]\s*\[Data\]/,"[Data]")}1' file
[Data]

hi

[Data]

one two three

[Data]

right left

[Data]
```

I emphasize "SAY" because your posted expected output doesn't match your description of what you want to do (`i need to look if between [Data] and [Data] have no text, if not contain text i need to delete the [Data] line and the next empty line.`) in as much as it also seems to delete a "[Data]" line at the end of the file.